# How to use the SSL autoconfiguration with a base64 encoded PKCS12?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-autoconfiguration

I have a Spring Boot 3.1 application with the following configuration:

```yaml
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      pem:
        my-client:
          keystore:
            certificate: "MIIKyAIBAzCCC..."
            private-key: "keystore-password"
            type: "PKCS12"
```

**Note:** The value of certificate is actually a keystore containing a root, an intermediate and a leaf certificate.

Running the applications results in the following exception:

```
Application run failed java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vcap/app/MIIKyAIBAzCCC...
```

Nowhere in the documentation is specified that it has to be a file resource.

Documentation link: https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/07/securing-spring-boot-applications-with-ssl

**So my question is**: how do I make the spring autoconfiguration work with an Base64 encoded keystore (in string format)?

In case you're looking for the autoconfiguration class, it's: `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslProperties`

Comment: Your error message contains the path `/home/vcap/app/MIIKyAIBAzCCC...`, which makes it appear that your app is running on Cloud Foundry. Is CF encoding the PKCS12 keystore somehow, or are you doing that yourself?

Comment: We have a system that we can run when we need a new  certificate. It automatically creates an base64 encoded certificate chain in p12 format and pushes that to credhub available for our app to be picked up. 
I have already filed a PR to spring-boot to support reading this type of keystore: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/35890

Answer (score 1):

I filed a PR to support having a base64 encoded PKCS#12 keystore here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/35890

Spring authors then thought this would be a good idea to implement it for a broader scope and closed the PR without merging it. Instead, they created an issue out of it, see issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36033

We should be able to use this from Spring Boot 3.2.x

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36033 has been completed for Spring Boot 3.3. With the support added for that issue, you should be able to use something like `certificate: "base64:MIIKyAIBAzCCC..."`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/21a54ec66dbde6a8d620506ce32c095665012497/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ssl/PemSslBundleProperties.java#L60), the property could be the "content" or the "location" in PEM format.

```java
/**
 * Location or content of the certificate in PEM format.
 */
String certificate;
```

There is nothing about the encoding of the content certificate in base64 and PKCS12 is not a PEM

Checking at the code that [loads the keystore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/21a54ec66dbde6a8d620506ce32c095665012497/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/ssl/pem/PemContent.java#L45-L60), you can see that the distinction between "content" or "location" is based on the first characters matching the usual header of PEM files

```java
private static boolean isPemContent(String content) {
    return content != null && PEM_HEADER.matcher(content).find() && PEM_FOOTER.matcher(content).find();
}
```

Note:
You can see that the location expect and URI. If Java would support natively the `data` scheme in url ([Does it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616422/is-there-a-way-to-add-data-scheme-support-rfc-2397-to-java-net-url)), this should became possible

```yaml
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      pem:
        my-client:
          keystore:
            certificate: "data:application/x-pkcs12,MIIKyAIBAzCCC..."
```

**To your answer**: You cannot use autoconfigure with a PKCS12 encoded in base64 without some extra steps.